# Winter 19' Release exam for Salesforce administrator

Tags: administration, certification, winter19

Can anybody share me link to take up Winter 19 release maintenance exam for Salesforce Administrator...

Answer (score 1):

It's in Trailhead now - you can do it directly there rather than via Web assessor.

[Administrator Certification Maintenance (Winter ’19)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/admin_cert_maintenance_winter19)